# Heat maps of average score and page views of questions by time and day of week

Tags: discussion, voting, views

I came across [this blog post](https://maxcandocia.com/article/2017/Jul/29/what-time-to-post-to-reddit/) that did analysis of the most popular times and days to post on Reddit, and had the idea to try it myself for SO. I parsed roughly 2 years worth of XML data from the [archive](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange), grouped the data by time and day of posting, found the averages for the scores and views for each time, and graphed the results using [Incanter](http://incanter.org/) as a heat-map.

I thought I'd share the results here. The below images show the mean score and view count that questions achieved, grouped by the day of the week and hour (in UTC) that the question was posted:

[image: Colorized Scores and View Counts by Hour and Time of Day]

Please excuse the x-axis labeling. It's proving abnormally difficult to fix.

Some interesting things:

- The score chart is somewhat opposite of the Reddit results. Reddit posts have more success when posted on the weekends, whereas SO posts seem to do much worse on the weekends.
- Views however seem to depend more on time of day than on the day of the week.
- ... which means the views to a question don't necessarily correlate with the score of the question.

And some things to note:

- View counts are not adjusted for question age.
- The post hour is the result of rounding. 15:29 would become 15:00, while 15:30 would become 16:00.
- The data is, as mentioned above, supplied by Stack Exchange's [archive](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) of dumped data, which indicates the state of the site as of roughly 2018-12-02 04:52:10.250 (the time of the last included post).

Obviously, this information isn't quite as useful as it is on Reddit unless you're really willing to withhold asking until a particular time. I still thought that it was interesting though.

---

It should be noted that I only included data:

- with a [`PostTypeId` of `1`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/300788) (questions).
- posted on or after 2016/01/01 00:00:00, and up to the date of the data dump (2018/12/02). I figured data more than a few years old is less relevant to now.
- that wasn't deleted, since I don't have access that information.

---

Here's a simpler black and white version for colorblind people like me, and those who want a less noisy representation:

[image: Grey-scale Scores and View Counts by Hour and Time of Day]

Comment: Heh. I guess I'm not the only one who spends too much time on SO while I'm at work...

Comment: If you swap hour/day you can have a wider heatmap with a way smaller height, that can fit nicely in a laptop/desktop screen (I'm thinking about something with [these proportions](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Tc8VenUN4n8/maxresdefault.jpg), for instance). On top of that, it would allow an easier comparison between hours in different days (by just moving the eye up/down).

Comment: @GerardoFurtado That should be trivial to change. I can try that tomorrow. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Carcigenicate if SO had a API for retrieving that data (or if we had it in a JSON/CSV somewhere) we could show that heatmap live, using JS in the Stack snippet!

Comment: @GerardoFurtado It actually does have a usable API. I could make a live version fairly easily with the code I've already written. I figured a long-time-span version would be more interesting though, and the API is impractical to use when gathering data over the span of a couple years.

Comment: Also, the request/day limits of the API would limit how often a "live" result could be generated.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Another idea: I'm seeing that you have UTC hours, but it's hard to understand how does that translate to each user's hour (for instance, why so many views at 5am? Are people insomniac or is that because 5am UTC is late night in US?)... so, what do you think about a *small multiples* of heatmaps? Something like what [I did here](https://gerardofurtado.com/dh/drugharms.html). You could create a small heatmap for each country. That way you can have **local time** in each heatmap, allowing us to really see the differences in different countries.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I concur. UTC is the normal way of displaying time on SO; and this way there are just two graphs. 'Shifting' the graph for each timezone is an unnecessary replication of data. A simple table/additional y-tick to tell people about 'noon in Europe' would be sufficient I'd say.

Comment: Well, my point is that aggregating all the data in a single heatmat using UTC doesn't tell us how the user behaves, it just tell us how the site as a whole behaves: a give hour may be more red just because a given country with a big population is more active at that time. On the other hand, creating small multiples (by country or, as an alternative, by time zone) would really tell us how the **users** behave.

Comment: @Adriaan I was thinking of adding horizontal lines showing where noon is in a few key places.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I still beg to differ. You'd get a map of how the world behaves at that certain moment, unless one can discern visitors based on their location (which only the devs can afaik), so you'd simply shift the map, as I said. Carcigenicates idea of adding noon in a few 'key places' (however one may choose those) is much more useful imo.

Comment: @Adriaan I believe we are actually agreeing about what we have. My point is just that this, from a data visualisation perspective, tells how the world (or the site, if you want) behaves, not how the users behave along the day. Hence my opinion that a small multiples by country is more useful to show the users' habits.

Comment: I assume "view count by hour" means "view count per hour", that is, number of views divided by age of the post, measured on 2018/12/02. If yes, this is a weird metric, because of the great differences it has for different questions. How do you average these vastly different numbers? Maybe you could better take a very narrow sample of questions, e.g. age of 7-14 days, to mitigate the effect of years of activity on differences by hour/weekday.

Comment: @anatolyg No, it's showing the number of views that a question ended up with at the time of archiving, sorted by the hour the question was posted at (rounded). The view counts are not adjusted for the age of the post. Older questions will have more views, but that shouldn't matter. If I had tried to group posts by month of posting (which I was originally going to do), January would be skewed since it's had more time to gather views. The effect over a single week should be negligible though.

Comment: Are the questions archived at some specific point in time, like 2 days after posting, or on each Wednesday? It seems to be common knowledge, but some people don't know it. You might want to specify in your post what exactly the numbers mean.

Comment: @anatolyg The archive is a snapshot of the state of the site as of 2018-12-02 04:52:10.250 UTC (the date of the last post in the archive). It appears to be done irregularly. I can make this clearer.

Comment: This is really cool! People that complain about colors and colormaps are often annoying. Still, I'd like to suggest another colormap in this case. Looks like you're using `jet`? `Parula` perhaps? I think another one like [cool](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/10/16/how-bad-is-your-colormap/) would do your research more justice.

Comment: @vestland Are you referring to the color scheme? That's the default. I only figured out how to change it after I had created this. It's actually a hardcoded list of 3-tuples representing the colors, so I don't think it's a named scheme. I could play around. I'm actually not a fan of the one I used here since I'm red/green color blind, but I figured that wouldn't be a big deal for most other people.

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to the color scheme. It's not a big deal to me personally. I have high regards for interesting research and thorough analysis. Design and colors always come second. In this particular case, though, with so much great information packed into a concentrated format, I think it's a bit hard to see the differences from high to low. A scheme with two clear extremes would make things easier. The green between the blue and red gets a bit messy. Especially when comparing which time category has the strongest impact. Day or week? Even a simple grayscale would potentially be "better".

Comment: @vestland I generated a simple BW one. See the bottom. It's definitely easier for me to differentiate close colors now.

Comment: In my humble opinion I think that's a vast improvement though some may find it a bit boring. In any case, where do you plan to post it on reddit? Dataisbeautiful?

Comment: @vestland I posted it on r/dataisbeautiful this morning.

Comment: @Carcigenicate,  Thanks for the black and white version. At first my brain looked at those color and told me : "it would make a great tee-shirt, can't tell more than that! Try tilting your head to the right.. your other right!"