# Is there a backup of the content of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Specifically, is there a browsable read-only copy of the questions and answers hosted on servers that would keep running if the company underlying Stack Exchange turned off the servers?

As Stack Overflow is rather popular, and so are terms like backup and archive, this has defeated my search engine skills.

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://archive.org/download/stackexchange ? It's not browseable like the online copy of Stack Overflow, but all the content is preserved and can even be downloaded at will.

Comment: Or perhaps something more like the [many sites that scrape Stack Overflow content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253906/7795130)

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19579/where-are-the-stack-exchange-data-dumps

Comment: You can pull the whole content as a weekly data dump.

Comment: The dump works great as long as you have the means to read a 80gb XML file. I've used it for past projects.

Comment: @Carcigenicate which was? "coding on a desert island" ? :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thankfully no. It was a fun little [data science project I did](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380784/heat-maps-of-average-score-and-page-views-of-questions-by-time-and-day-of-week).

Comment: @halfer: Isn't that the SEDE update rate? And the dump every few months?

Comment: @Peter - you may be right. [These data dumps](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange) were refreshed at the start of Q4 this year.